# Linq - Project List<A> to grouped List<B> with a C object within List<B>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, grouping

I have classes like:

```
public class A {
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Hour { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}

public class B {
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public C C { get; set; }
}

public class C {
    public int Hour { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

I have a `List<A>` which contains a series of dates with hourly values for each. I'm trying to convert it from that format to that of type B, so a `List<B>`.

For instance, if there were 3 days' worth of data in the `List<A>` (i.e. 24 x 3 = 72 records), then there should be 3 objects of type B in the `List<B>` - one for each day with the 24 hours split up into the C type.

I know I can do it with nested foreach loops but I figured LINQ would be more elegant and would likely be better performance wise as well.

The code I'm trying is:

```
var res = from a in AList
          select (new List<B>
          {
              new B
              {
                  Date = a.Date,
                  C = new C() 
                  { 
                      Hour = a.Hour, 
                      Value = a.Value 
                  }
              }
          });
```

But it returns a list without the date grouping. I'm not sure how to establish that grouping. Would appreciate any help!

Comment: you can group with `group a by a.Date into bgroup` and then select from that by `from b in bgroup select new B { Date = bgroup.Key, new C(b.Hour, b.Value) } ` instead of selecting b from a directly.

Comment: See webpage : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logically, it seems like your `B` class should contain a *collection* of `C` instances:

```
public class B {
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public ICollection<C> C { get; set; }
}
```

Consequently, you could use `group by` to populate these instances:

```
var res = 
(
    from a in AList
    group a by a.Date into g
    select new B
    {
        Date = g.Key,
        C = 
        (
            from c in g
            select new C
            { 
                Hour = c.Hour, 
                Value = c.Value 
            }
        ).ToList()
    }
).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the catch, you're absolutely right.. I needed a collection of C, can't believe I missed that. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
        var newAList = from a in AList
                       select new B 
                       { 
                           Date = a.Date,
                           C = new C { Hour = a.Hour, Value = a.Value }
                       };
```

LINQ: Elegant? Yes. But better performance than nested loops? I'm not sure about it.